# Spring Tool Suite 3.8.3 RELEASE installation

Tags: spring-tool-suite

I have been downloading http://download.springsource.com/release/STS/3.8.3.RELEASE/dist/e4.6/spring-tool-suite-3.8.3.RELEASE-e4.6.2-win32-x86_64.zip but I cannot find STS.exe as in prior versions. This is not explained on the download page https://spring.io/tools so how do I install it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The STS.exe is included in that ZIP file (right inside the sts-3.8.3.RELEASE folder). Maybe a proxy server or a virus scanner removed the EXE from the ZIP file (some of those proxy and virus scanners remove any EXE by default for security reasons). I would guess that is the case for you if the STS.exe file is missing from your downloaded ZIP file.

Comment: I have just been re-downloading it and now the files are there. I don't have a proxy and no virus scanner apart from windows defender. So I guess I did something wrong without realising what I did.

Comment: glad to hear that you got it working and thanks for letting us know.